# Make list from list of lists with condition

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm currently stucked with recursion over lists of lists.

The task is quite simple in any imperative language: iterate over every professor, iterate over professor's course list, and get every course that matches CourseNumber given as predicate argument to output var CourseList.

I have simple solution (other ones just fail with out of stack or returns empty list), but as you can see, it checks only if the head of the course's list matches cond.

```
get_teaching_courses(CourseNumber, CourseList) :-
    findall(Course,
            (
              professor(_, [Course | _]),
              member(CourseNumber, Course)
            ),
            CourseList).
```

professor fact has next struct:

```
professor(Name, [ [CourseName , CourseNumber], .... ]).
```

I am thinking of making predicate over predicate, but I can't achieve it (something wrong with append I guess).

It's been like 2 days I've started learning prolog, and if you can give me any help, advice or link that can help me, I'd appreciate it.

example:

```
assertz(
        professor(
                    'Bob',
                    [
                        ['Math', 2],
                        ['PE', 3]
                    ]
                 )
       ).
```

Solution:

```
get_teaching_courses(CourseNumber, CourseList) :-
    findall(CourseName,
            (
              professor(_, Course),
              member([CourseName, CourseNumber], Course)
            ),
            CourseList).
```

thanks to @CapelliC and his answer.

Comment: It would help if you would give us some sample data and a sample of expected results.

Comment: Can multiple, different courses have the same course number? Your predicate seems to imply that they can.

Comment: @lurker yes, that's the main goal.

Comment: try `member([_,CourseNumber], Course)`

Comment: @Capellic it is pretty same thing I did. I need to check it for all courses in list, not only the the first one.

Comment: it's not the same, you should try to understand pattern matching. member/2 will do on backtracking, driven by findall/3

Comment: @CapelliC thank you very much, now it seems clear. How can I mark your answer as solution to close question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the incorrect pattern matching applied in member/2. Try

```
member([_,CourseNumber], Course)
```